# How to convert this XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file formatted like

```
<paragraph> Some Free text goes here<LinkType1 href="link1" >LinkName1</LinkType1> Then some more text <LinkType2 href="link2" >LinkName2</LinkType2>Then some more text <LinkType1 href =link3" >LinkName3</LinkType1> and then some more text
</paragraph>
```

This XML represents a paragraph of text with some links embedded inside it. In other words it is text and nodes within this text.

I need to convert it to HTML that looks like:

```
<p>
Some Free text goes here<a href="link1" target="_blank" >LinkName1</a> Then some more text <a href="link2"  target="_blank" >LinkName2</a>Then some more text <a href =link3"  target="_blank" >LinkName3</a> and then some more text
</p>
```

How can I do such transformation with XSLT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'LinkType')]">
  <a href="{@href}" target="_blank" >
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to become well-formed !):

```
<paragraph> Some Free text goes here
    <LinkType1 href="link1" >LinkName1</LinkType1> Then some more text 
    <LinkType2 href="link2" >LinkName2</LinkType2>Then some more text 
    <LinkType1 href ="link3" >LinkName3</LinkType1> and then some more text 
</paragraph>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p> Some Free text goes here
    <a href="link1" target="_blank">LinkName1</a> Then some more text 
    <a href="link2" target="_blank">LinkName2</a>Then some more text 
    <a href="link3" target="_blank">LinkName3</a> and then some more text 
</p>
```